# Event based reminders when leaving your home or another location, forgot your keys?

Tags: android

I am looking for a reminder when I leave home. E.g, "have you got your keys, wallet, glasses?"

I have considered, without success, google's location based reminder but they just do not seem to work accurately and I see no option for when leaving a location like 'home' only when entering a location like 'home'.

The closest solution I have found is an app on ios that will allow you to set a coordinate and using the phone's built in step counter it will deternind when you go "so many steps" out of the coordinate then it will fire a reminder. Unfortunaty the app "dont leave it" is ios only.

Then there's bluetooth tags you can buy and clip into things like keys wallet. But this offers less flexibility and is exspensive.

I have been thinking what if you could anchor your phone via bluetooth to a device in your house such as a bluetooth speaker or a google home device and when you leave your home and the connection goes out of range then your "leave home" reminders would notify. But then bluetooth range is pretty far like 15M? Nobody wants to go back up 4 flights of stairs to remember you forgot plastic carrier bags for grocery shopping.

An ideal solution, one I cannot see existing already, would be NFC scanners to the left and right of the house exit door that will interact with your phone's NFC to trigger event based reminders.
Forgive the lack of technological terms, I am approaching this topic at a very high level understanding off technology.

Does a geofencing event based reminder solution for android devices, that has not been mentioned, exist?

Regards
Mike

Comment: And the question is ...?

Comment: I have movef the question to the bottom of the text and reworded it to make it clearer. Thank you